# How to Get the latest and oldest row from group by min/max in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have an app where I am selecting records with first and the last timestamp for that day. There are more than one rows that satisfies the criteria, I want only the latest for that specific day.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP, COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id) 
    FROM attendance 
        WHERE Date(TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2019', '%d/%m/%Y') 
                                  AND STR_TO_DATE('30/04/2019', '%d/%m/%Y') 
          AND TIME(TIMESTAMP) < '17:00' 
          AND employee_id=1111 
    GROUP BY DATE(TIMESTAMP);
```

The problem is that it doesn't return the last/latest records for those days.

[image]

Sample data[image]

Comment: could you please provide sample data and your expected output

Comment: Maybe adding `MAX(TIME(TIMESTAMP))` in your `SELECT`

Comment: yeah I have tried that Max but no success.

Comment: What is COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id)  supposed to do - is it the employees for each day or employees over the entire period specified in the where clause? Sample data and expected output would help clarify.

Comment: @P.Salmon It is to count the distinct entries per day.

Comment: I don't know how it's duplicate ? I have checked the answer and it doesn't help me in any way.  :/

Answer (score 1):

If you want day wise, oldest and latest entry in particular date range then you can group by date column and order by timestamp column.

Query for fetching latest entry:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP, COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id) 
   FROM attendance 
        WHERE Date(TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2019', '%d/%m/%Y') 
          AND STR_TO_DATE('30/04/2019', '%d/%m/%Y') 
          AND TIME(TIMESTAMP) < '17:00' 
          AND employee_id=1111 
        GROUP BY DATE(TIMESTAMP)
        ORDER BY(TIMESTAMP) DESC;
```

Query for fetching oldest entry:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP, COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id) 
    FROM attendance 
        WHERE Date(TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2019', '%d/%m/%Y') 
                                  AND STR_TO_DATE('30/04/2019', '%d/%m/%Y') 
           AND TIME(TIMESTAMP) < '17:00' 
           AND employee_id=1111 
        GROUP BY DATE(TIMESTAMP)
        ORDER BY(TIMESTAMP) ASC;
```

Please note, I have only used GROUP BY statement and ORDER BY DESC/ASC (based on your requirement for fetching latest/oldest data respectively which matches with the specified criteria).

Hope it works!

Comment: no, I actually want latest record for each day in the date range. I have used between as you can see.

Comment: Note that functions (as above) cannot use indexes, so this will be painfully slow on larger data sets.

Comment: @AdnanNazir, I have updated the solution by removing LIMIT from Query and adding Group By date column to get day wise oldest and latest data.

Comment: @GirlHasNoName It still returns values that are not max and also the values are duplicated.